# Switching between buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

How can i make dynamic switching between buttons? For example if one button is active, then the rest is not active. For example:

```js
     constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      active: false,
      notactive: false
    }
  }

  checkActive = () => {
    this.setState({
      active: true,
      notactive: false
    })
  };

  checkNotactive = () => {
    this.setState({
      active: false,
      notactive: true
    })
  };
```

But i want make it dynamic. 
I mean that when I have, for example, 10 buttons, I will not set each state apart. If I add another button, it will work. Just like the radio button.

Comment: how about storing the index of the active button in state?

Comment: in state hold the `name` of the button that is active then check for disabled like `<button disabled={this.state.activeName !== 'thisButtonName'} ... />` or alternatively if you are rendering the buttons from an array you could store the _index_ of the button that is active

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a boolean you could use an index to mark the active button.

Eg:

```
this.state = {
    activeButtonIndex: null
}
```

then when creating your buttons using a loop you can check

```
if (index === this.state.activeButtonIndex) { do something }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have a type property based on your buttons. If for example you need to make 3 buttons daily, weekly, monthly then you can have something like this.

```
return (
  <div style={style.buttonContainer}>
    <div className={this.props.active === "daily" ? "activeButton" : ""}>
      <Button color="primary" onClick={this.handleClick("daily")}>
        Daily
      </Button>
    </div>
    <div className={this.props.active === "weekly" ? "activeButton" : ""}>
      <Button color="primary" onClick={this.handleClick("weekly")}>
        Weekly
      </Button>
    </div>
    <div className={this.props.active === "monthly" ? "activeButton" : ""}>
      <Button color="primary" onClick={this.handleClick("monthly")}>
        Monthly
      </Button>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

I have a property on parent's state `active` and based on that I will switch dynamically.